# What should I do if a question is not a duplicate just because of some tag, but the OP accepts an answer that does not use the tag?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

To give a specific example, I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70987497/525036) which seems to involve a somewhat common problem, so I searched for duplicates.

I found a similar question, but it didn’t have the [java-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-stream) tag and answers were thus not relevant if you wanted a solution using streams, so I just mentioned it in the comments of the first question.

Now the OP has accepted an answer that does not involve [java-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-stream) (at all), and there is another similar answer. I had posted comments on both that they did not seem relevant due to the question’s tag, but it seems I was wrong.

In retrospect, I could have done the following:

- as the question itself does not mention anything related to [java-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-stream) (it is only tagged with it), I could have removed the tag and vote for duplicate closure
- in addition, I could have added a stream-based solution to the duplicate I found

What should I do now? Remove the tag and propose for duplicate closure, and if/when it gets closed, just remove all my comments?

Comment: I am fairly confident there exists a duplicate that does use streams.

Comment: I'd do exactly what you propose, vote to dupe close (because it's a duplicate) and remove the tag (because it's clear now that it's not relevant to OP). I don't think you did anything wrong here, you asked OP to confirm that the stream tag was relevant, but they've made clear now that it wasn't by accepting an answer that didn't use streams.

Comment: @zcoop98 not all users know what accepting an answer means, especially new users. Somebody can accept an answer because they think it is customary, or because they appreciate that someone spent some time on their question, even if the answer is not applicable and the OP knows this. In the example question above the OP didn't provide any feedback on the comments or other answers at all apart from the accept, so I wouldn't conclude that they "made clear now" that the tag was incorrect.

Comment: I removed the tag and VTC'd as duplicate. Nowhere in the body of the question did the OP indicate they need a stream-based solution, and doing so *now* would *invalidate* existing answers made in good faith when it was not obvious that the question requires such a solution - constituting a violation of editing guidelines. If the OP wants a [tag:java-stream] solution, they can always ask a new question *explicitly* requesting it. As of now, it is nothing more than a duplicate - don't forget that tags are *metadata* and have to describe what the question is about, not the other way around.

Comment: I routinely remove irrelevant details from questions, that includes titles, body and tags.

Comment: @Braiam oh yes, me too, even on this very question. It’s just that this tag might have been relevant here.

Comment: I do the opposite, if it isn't _prima facie_ why it's relevant, it's out. Basically, go to the bone directly and see if it's still the same question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Once the OP accepts an answer (perhaps with a bit of time given for some "are you sure" discussion in the comments), you have fairly conclusive evidence of what they are willing to accept as an implementation method. At that point, you can safely discard any concern about not using a technology that was specified in their question.

If you know of a good duplicate target, and the only reason you weren't closing the question as a duplicate of said target was because of that specified technology, you're now safe to vote to close/dupehammer the question, in my view.

I recommend leaving the tag in, however, because that can signal to someone who may be able to provide a stream-based answer (in this particular example). OP might be interested in a stream-based solution still, even if they are able to use a different one in the end. You could rephrase the question as necessary so that it's clear streams aren't *required* for solutions, just preferred or "interesting" or something.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, there is already a stream-based answer and the OP chose not to accept it. I don’t think it makes sense to tag questions with any potential technology/framework that could be used to answer them.

Comment: @DidierL I haven't read the question you referenced, but it sounded like they specifically requested a stream-based solution in the OP... if they didn't, and simply added the stream tag, then yeah it's probably no concern to delete it, but then I wouldn't have let that stop me from closing the question as a duplicate in the first place, if it were only a tag and no explicit request in the body.

Comment: Indeed, I figured I should probably have done that.